# mysql join table

Tags: php, mysql, database, database-design

I have 4 tables.

1. Table A that has users -  (`user_id, username, and name`)
2. Table B that has tokens - (`token_id, user_id`).  Each user has 10 token entries. Each token is assigned to only one user.  A user has multiple tokens (10)
3. Table C that is arcades games - (`arcade_id, token_id, name, levels, lives`).  Only one token can be assigned to one arcade game only.
4. Table D that is prizes - (`prize_id, token_id, name, length, width, height`).  Only one token can be assigned to one prize only.

A token is assigned to either an arcade game or a prize or nothing but not both.

My question is how do set-up a MySQL join query to figure out which tokens for a given user are assigned to game or a prize or have not been assigned yet. Are my table layouts optimal? Or do you have suggestions for another layout?

Here are my tables:

```
mysql> select * from users;

+---------+--------+
| user_id | name   |
+---------+--------+
|       1 | User 1 |
|       2 | User 2 |
|       3 | User 3 |
|       4 | User 4 |
+---------+--------+

mysql> select * from tokens;

+----------+---------+
| token_id | user_id |
+----------+---------+
|        1 |       1 |
|        2 |       1 |
|        3 |       2 |
|        4 |       2 |
|        5 |       2 |
|       11 |       2 |
|        6 |       3 |
|        7 |       3 |
|       10 |       3 |
|        8 |       4 |
|        9 |       4 |
+----------+---------+

mysql> select * from prizes;

+----------+----------+-----------+
| prize_id | token_id | prizename |
+----------+----------+-----------+
|        1 |        4 | prize 1   |
|        2 |        7 | prize 2   |
|        3 |        8 | prize 3   |
|        4 |        9 | prize 4   |
+----------+----------+-----------+

mysql> select * from arcade;

+-----------+----------+----------+
| arcade_id | token_id | gamename |
+-----------+----------+----------+
|         1 |        1 | game 1   |
|         2 |        2 | game 2   |
|         3 |        3 | game 3   |
|         4 |        5 | game 4   |
|         5 |       11 | game 6   |
+-----------+----------+----------+
```

I would like a SQL query where I can get the following info:

For User 1, they have 2 tokens - token id 1 is assigned to game 1 and token id 2 is assigned to game 2

Or for user 2 - they have 4 tokens - token id 3 is assigned to game 3, token id 4 is assigned to prize 1, token id 5 is assigned to game 4.

Or for user 3 - they have 3 tokens - token id 6 is not assigned yet, token id 7 is prize 2, token id 10 is not assigned

and so on.

I would like to build a MySQL query string like this

```sql
Select **** 
  from ***** 
 Where user_id = 1
```

Where I specify the user id and get all the info above.

Comment: can you please provide some sample data on http://sqlfiddle.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query but if there was some data i would be able to check although i have checked with dummy data

```
select
  t.token_id,
  IFNULL(g.game,'') as Game,
  IFNULL(p.name,'') as Prize,
  case when g.game != '' then 'Assigned' when p.name != '' then 'Assigned' else 'Not assigned yet' end as `Status`
from token as t
  left join (select *
         from games
         where token_id not in(select
                     token_id
                   from prize)) as g
    on g.token_id = t.token_id
  left join (select *
         from prize
         where token_id not in(select
                     token_id
                   from games)) as p
    on p.token_id = t.token_id
```

EDITED
Then it should be the most simple thing to do

```
select *
from `user`
  left join token
    on user.user_id = token.user_id
  left join games
    on games.token_id = token.token_id
  left join prize
    on prize.token_id = token.token_id
where user.user_id = 1
```